# Can I select a specific image from a sort order using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

such as
I randomly selected 10 pictures, I want the 6th picture to use.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you give some more information and code? I mean if they are in an array or list sure you could apply your PIL functions on listname[5].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Something like this?

```py
pictures_list = [pic1, pic2, ..., pic10]  # define pictures list
pictures_list.sort()  # sort pictures
pic = pictures_list[5] # returns 6th picture
```